# ng-repeat filter and repeat by heading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Trying to separate a group of filters that come back from a search that I am doing in my angular app. When I do the search i receive back the json and it is grouped by heading. Can I only repeat the items in that particular group and separate them that way? The reason is that each group will be in a unique UI module. So some of the list will be returned and displayed in a slider and some will be in radios.

Here is the:

```
<div heading="{{filter.name}}" 
     ng-repeat="filter in inventory.filters | filterOptions | orderBy:'name'" 
     is-open="true" show-attrs>
  <h3>{{filter.name | uppercase}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
      <span ng-click="selectedFilter(filter, option.option, option.id)">
      <a>{{option.option}}{{option.count>0 ? "("+option.count +")": ""}}</a>
      </span>
      <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

So ultimately I would like to be able to target the filter.name.color and when it is this particular group have it display in this particular type of UI.

Any suggestions or links to readings is appreciated.

Comment: Actually I may have found what I am looking for but will leave this open in case anyone has some input on best practices. Using ng-if="filter.name=='blah'" in a div wrapper before after the ng-repeat call but before the UI display let me at least just limit the filter that was being shown.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Well I'm not sure I am doing it correctly. I have found that with javascript, just because I can do something does not make it correct or prevent it from stomping on the dom.

Comment: Even so, you should post it so that people can improve upon it. Doing so would also help clarify what it is that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your posted answer it looks like what you want to do is only show filters that have a particular name. If so, [`ngFilter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) should be able to take care of this like so:

```
| filter:{name: 'blah'}
```

(or `{name: something}` if the value is in a variable called `something`)

Full HTML:

```
<div heading="{{filter.name}}" 
     ng-repeat="filter in inventory.filters | filterOptions | orderBy:'name' | filter:{name:'blah'}" 
     is-open="true" show-attrs>
  <h3>{{filter.name | uppercase}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
    <span ng-click="selectedFilter(filter, option.option, option.id)"><a>{{option.option}}{{option.count>0 ? "("+option.count +")": ""}}</a></span>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <!--Then I just repeat each ng-if that I want to be available -->
</div>
```

If you want to filter based on `filter.name.color`, you can use `| filter:{name.color: 'blue'}`, but if having that dot in the object notation doesn't sit quite right with you, an alternate option is to use a custom filter function:

```
| filter:hasColor.bind(null, 'blue')
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.hasColor = function (color, filter) {
    return filter.name && filter.name.color === color;
};
```

Comment: It seems to be working how I have it without the addition of filter in the repeat options but going to use your idea for some other items. I need to try and find a way to work these into a html5 range input and I think your method may be better for those. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I tried was this and it seemed to get me some control over what I am showing and where:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div heading="{{filter.name}}" 
     ng-repeat="filter in inventory.filters | filterOptions | orderBy:'name'" 
     is-open="true" show-attrs>
  <div ng-if="filter.name=='blah'" >
    <h3>{{filter.name | uppercase}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="option in filter.options">
      <span ng-click="selectedFilter(filter, option.option, option.id)"><a>{{option.option}}{{option.count>0 ? "("+option.count +")": ""}}</a></span>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Then I just repeat each ng-if that I want to be available -->
</div>
```

So basically after the ng-repeat call within that div I am calling and nf-if and targeting the specific filter heading name/id to get only what I need to do.